# How to load a JavaFX controller with parameters?

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to initialize a controller of an FXML file with parameters?
Here is my code:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
try {
    loader.setLocation(this.fichierUIFxml.getURL());
    loader.load();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my FXML code:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.inexa.fix.ui.view.controller.UIController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1408.0" stylesheets="style/ui.css" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
    ...
</VBox>
```

Here is the controller I want to initialize:

```
public class UIController {
    public ProgressIndicator progressIndicator;
    @Value("classpath:ordre.fxml")
    Resource fichierOrdreFxml;

    private AuthentificationController authentificationController;
    
    public UIController(VMLogiqueAuthentification vmLogiqueAuthentification) {
        this.authentificationController = new AuthentificationController(vmLogiqueAuthentification);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Thanks @Kiraged, I will check it.

Comment: Excellent job designing your question.